# Loop through SQLite_master table and delete tables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql, ios, sqlite

The code below partially works.  Its supposed to return all the tables in the sqlite_master table and then delete them.

```
 NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';"];

        sqlite3_stmt *statement = [database prepare:sql];
        if(statement != nil)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString* currentTable = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                if ([currentTable rangeOfString:@"sqlite"].location == NSNotFound && 
                    [currentTable rangeOfString:@"Setting"].location == NSNotFound)
                {
                    NSLog(@"current table: %@", currentTable);
                    [database deleteTable: currentTable];
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
```

However, after calling `[database deleteTable: currentTable];` the tables are not being deleted.

delete table is just an `sqlite3_exec` which accepts the sql: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '%@'", tableName]`

Why is this?  Is it because whilst i'm in the loop the database is in use?  Would I be better putting the results in an array and than looping through and deleting tables that way? No exceptions are thrown/crashes etc and the exec is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finalizing using `sqlite3_finalize` after every delete.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I assume you mean finalize sqlite3_exec on delete not the statment?

Comment: Yes.  I've found that you really have to call finalize after any calls that affect the database.